# sqlite3 query by column name in several databases with similar structure

Tags: sqlite

I would like to query several databases that all have the same structure. Ideally, I would like to combine all databases into one that I could query as if we had only one only, for specific queries that I do from time to time. However, I haven't found anything like this in the documentation.

As far as I know I only can use `attach` and `join` the tables but it can get difficult to manage when using more than 3-4 tables. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'db1.db' AS db1;
ATTACH DATABASE 'db2.db' AS db2;
select * from db1.id as a join db2.id as b where a.status='on' AND a.status=b.status;
```

However, if I try to get column 'name' only for both tables I haven't been able to make it work:

```
select name from db1.id as a join db2.id as b where a.status='on' AND a.status=b.status;
```

Comment: What is the error message? And which one of the two names do you want?

Comment: @CL I would like to get both

Comment: @CL The error is "Error: ambiguous column name: name".

Comment: @CL the question linked refer to a query joining 2 tables not 2 databases with similar tables. I do not see how is this related.

Comment: The actual problem is the same (identical column names), and the solution is also the same.